# php x = 0 or y = 1 not working in if string

Tags: php

```
if(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue === 0 || $ruavalue === 2) 
{
Echo "RUA: ";
$RUAresult = mysql_query("SELECT Answer FROM options"); 
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<input name=\"boss\" type=hidden value='".$_POST['tier_two']."'>";
echo "<input name=\"main\" type=hidden value='".$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']."'>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="ruasubmit" value="RUA!" />';
echo '</form>';
} else {
echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
}
```

when i use

```
if(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue == 0)
```

it works fine but i need to use

```
if(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue === 0 || $ruavalue === 2)
```

and it is not working correctly

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). See `&&` and `||`. The expression is evaluated as `((a && b) || c)`. You can use parenthesis to control how the expression is evaluated: `(a && (b || c))`.

Comment: i have tried both of the suggestions below and this has not fixed my issue

Comment: What are the values of `$drop` and `$ruavalue`? Also, what is the point of the database call? You never use it for anything.

Comment: its a value pulled from the mysql db, the point is to check the users status on RUA 0 = No RUA, 1 = Normal RUA 2 = Heroic RUA And 3 = Nomral And Heroic RUA

Comment: `var_dump($ruavalue)` please.

Comment: string(1) "2"  is what is returned

Comment: $drop = string(9) "soo10norm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment feedback it appears to be because of the [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) that you are using. You are using the "identical to" operator, `===`. The "identical to" operator not only compares the *value* of a variable but also the *type*.

Because `$ruavalue` is a *string* of value `"2"`, and in your `if` expression you are using the *integer* `2`, the expression will always evaluate to `false`; strings and integers can never be *identical to* each other, but they can be *equal to* each other.

You need to either use the "equal to" operator, `==`, or compare the variables to numbers as strings:

```
if (strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue == 0 || $ruavalue == 2)
if (strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue === '0' || $ruavalue === '2')
```

The [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) would also be important here. Your current expression is evaluated as such:

```
   ((a && b) || c)
=> (ab || c)
```

What you probably want is:

```
   (a && (b || c))
=> (a && bc)
```

In other words,

```
if (strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && ($ruavalue == 0 || $ruavalue == 2))
```

Comment: thank you this has fix my issue using if(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue === "0" || $ruavalue === "2")

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
if(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && ($ruavalue === 0 || $ruavalue === 2))
```

Comment: that has not fixed it :( it still displays You Have RUA'ed To This Boss

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ((strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false) && (($ruavalue == 0) || ($ruavalue == 2)))
```

Comment: that has not fixed it :( it still displays You Have RUA'ed To This Boss

Comment: still the same im afraid

Comment: What are the values of $drop and $ruavalue?

Comment: $drop = string(9) "soo10norm" And $ruavalue = string(1) "2"