# preg_match not working correctly?

Tags: php

I have recently updated one of my php files to allow for a new preg_match but it seems to work only in the first two instances

```
//Normal Values Check
if(preg_match("/norm/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "0" || $ruavalue === "2" || $ruavalue === "4" || $ruavalue === "6")
        {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';
        echo "<input name=\"drop1\" type=hidden value='".$drop."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"ruavalue1\" type=hidden value='".$ruavalue."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"boss\" type=hidden value='".$_POST['tier_two']."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"main\" type=hidden value='".$maintoonqry3."'>";
        echo '<input name="the_page" type=hidden value="RUA/rua-system.php">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="ruasubmit" value="RUA!" />';
        echo '</form>';
        } 
//Normal Values Achieved Then Inform User
        elseif(preg_match("/norm/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "1" || $ruavalue === "3" || $ruavalue === "5" || $ruavalue === "7") {
        echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
        }
//Heroic Values Check
        elseif(preg_match("/hc/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "0" || $ruavalue === "1" || $ruavalue === "4" || $ruavalue === "5") 
        {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';
        echo "<input name=\"drop1\" type=hidden value='".$drop."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"ruavalue1\" type=hidden value='".$ruavalue."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"boss\" type=hidden value='".$_POST['tier_two']."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"main\" type=hidden value='".$maintoonqry3."'>";
        echo '<input name="the_page" type=hidden value="RUA/rua-system.php">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="ruasubmit" value="RUA!" />';
        echo '</form>';
        } 
//Heroic Values Achieved Then Inform User
        elseif(preg_match("/hc/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "2" || $ruavalue === "3" || $ruavalue === "6" || $ruavalue === "7") {
        echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
        }
//Mythic Values Check
        elseif(preg_match("/myth/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "0" || $ruavalue === "1" || $ruavalue === "2" || $ruavalue === "3") 
        {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';
        echo "<input name=\"drop1\" type=hidden value='".$drop."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"ruavalue1\" type=hidden value='".$ruavalue."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"boss\" type=hidden value='".$_POST['tier_two']."'>";
        echo "<input name=\"main\" type=hidden value='".$maintoonqry3."'>";
        echo '<input name="the_page" type=hidden value="RUA/rua-system.php">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="ruasubmit" value="RUA!" />';
        echo '</form>';
        } 
//Mythic Values Achieved Then Inform User
        elseif(preg_match("/myth/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "4" || $ruavalue === "5" || $ruavalue === "6" || $ruavalue === "7") {
        echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
        }
```

The issue im having is that my 1st two button's will display fine but when my $ruavalue = 3 then my 3rd button will not work i dont know if im just being blind to the issue or if its particularly bad code

Comment: What it the content of `$drop`? `to work only in the first two instances` may be because only `norm` exists in a string? you do not need regexps, use `stripos`

Comment: its either highmaulnorm, highmaulhc or highmaulmyth it depends on the post value

Comment: Then all these `$ruavalue` do not satisfy condition. Show as the values of the variables.

Comment: checked that too, var_dump'ed the post and $ruavalue was 3 when the  $drop was highmaulmyth

Comment: whoa... that's a lot of code.  what are you actually trying to do?  what is the string and what are we doing to it (or testing it for)?

Comment: it checks the value of $drop from the post (highmaulnorm, highmaulhc or highmaulmyth), it then checks the users current value (1-7)
0 - Not RUA'ed | 
1 - RUA'ed Normal | 
2 - RUA'ed Heroic | 
3 - RUA'ed Normal & Heroic | 
4 - RUA'ed Mythic | 
5 - RUA'ed Normal & Mythic | 
6 - RUA'ed Heroic & Mythic | 
7 - RUA'ed Normal & Heroic & Mythic | this should then determine if the submit button should be displayed or confirmation text

Comment: [You do understand that there is a difference between **`==`** and **`===`**, specially when you're dealing with numbers right? Because **`3 === "3"`** is **false**.](https://eval.in/204451) So if the value received on the **`var_dump`** for **`$ruavalue`** is an **`int`** then it will fail. [You can read more about the comparison operators here...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: @prix i do indeed and i had not come across any issues in using this method until i added the mythic to the code which is when my issues arrose

Comment: [The problem was simple he missed some parenthesis to impose his logic, here is an example of it failing and below how it succeed with parenthesis at the proper places.](https://eval.in/204484) [**Which was also explained to you at your other question here.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23463320/342740) Where he tells you how you need to use it and despite marking as the right answer you ignored the right method. Which becomes a duplicate of [php x = 0 or y = 1 not working in if string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463130/php-x-0-or-y-1-not-working-in-if-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I like leaving those array values as strings, even though they're integers, just because of how my notepad++ colors them with syntax highlighting (text is grey, numbers are red, I like grey).  You could do it either way, though.

```
<?php 
$_POST['tier_two'] = 'tier_two';

$drop         = 'myth';
$ruavalue     = '9';
$tier_two     = $_POST['tier_two'];
$maintoonqry3 = 'ebola!'; 
// ----------------------------------------- 

$vals = array('drop'=>$drop,
              'ruavalue'=>$ruavalue,
              'tier_two'=>$tier_two,
              'maintoonqry3'=>$maintoonqry3); 

$test = array('norm'=>array('0','2','4','6'), 
              'hc'  =>array('0','1','4','5'),
              'myth'=>array('0','1','2','3')); 

foreach ($test as $key => $array) {
   if (preg_match("/$key/i", $drop)) {
      if (in_array($ruavalue,$array)) {
         display_my_form($vals);
      }
      else echo 'You Have RUA\'ed To This Boss'; 
      break;  // put this here if you only want to hit
              // the first key (norm,hc,myth) match, 
              // determine valid or not, an d then stop.  
   } 
}   

function display_my_form($vals) {
   echo "
   <form action='' method='post'>
      <input name='drop1'     type='hidden' value='{$vals['drop']}'>
      <input name='ruavalue1' type='hidden' value='{$vals['ruavalue']}'>
      <input name='boss'      type='hidden' value='{$vals['tier_two']}'>
      <input name='main'      type='hidden' value='{$vals['maintoonqry3']}'>
      <input name='the_page'  type='hidden' value='RUA/rua-system.php'>
      <input name='ruasubmit' type='submit' value='RUA!' />
   </form>
   ";
}
?>
```

---

wow....

k, so... i dunno.  i tested all regex and good/bad values for it all (both sections of code work).  not sure why you have those input fields hidden but that's alright.

```
<?php 
$_POST['tier_two'] = 'tier_two';   // for testing 

$drop         = 'myth'; 
$ruavalue     = '5'; 
$tier_two     = $_POST['tier_two']; 
$maintoonqry3 = 'ebola!';  

$vals = array('drop'=>$drop,'ruavalue'=>$ruavalue,
              'tier_two'=>$tier_two,'maintoonqry3'=>$maintoonqry3);   


if (preg_match('/norm/i', $drop)) {
   if (in_array($ruavalue,array('0','2','4','6'))) {
      display_my_form($vals);
   }
   else echo_error(); 
}

if (preg_match('/hc/i', $drop)) { 
   if (in_array($ruavalue,array('0','1','4','5'))) { 
      display_my_form($vals);
   }
   else echo_error();  
}

if (preg_match('/myth/i', $drop)) { 
   if (in_array($ruavalue,array('0','1','2','3'))) {
      display_my_form($vals);
   }
   else echo_error();  
}

function display_my_form($vals) {?>
   <form action='' method='post'>
      <input name='drop1'     type='hidden' value='<?php echo $vals['drop'] ?>'>
      <input name='ruavalue'  type='hidden' value='<?php echo $vals['ruavalue'] ?>'>
      <input name='boss'      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $vals['tier_two'] ?>'>
      <input name='main'      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $vals['maintoonqry3'] ?>'>
      <input name='the_page'  type='hidden' value='RUA/rua-system.php'>
      <input name='ruasubmit' type='submit' value='RUA!' />
   </form>
<?php  
}  

function echo_error() {
   echo 'You Have RUA\'ed To This Boss';
}  

?>
```

and if you want to keep it your way... this also functions:

```
<?php 
$_POST['tier_two'] = 'tier_two'; 


$drop         = 'myth'; 
$ruavalue     = '5'; 
$tier_two     = $_POST['tier_two']; 
$maintoonqry3 = 'ebola!'; 



if (preg_match('/norm/i', $drop) && in_array($ruavalue,array('0','2','4','6'))) { ?>
   <form action='' method='post'>
      <input name="drop1"     type='hidden' value='<?php echo $drop ?>'>
      <input name="ruavalue1" type='hidden' value='<?php echo $ruavalue ?>'>
      <input name="boss"      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST['tier_two'] ?>'>
      <input name="main"      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $maintoonqry3 ?>'>
      <input name='the_page'  type='hidden' value='RUA/rua-system.php'>
      <input name='ruasubmit' type='submit' value='RUA!' />
   </form>
<?php 
} elseif (preg_match("/norm/i", $drop) && in_array($ruavalue,array('1','3','5','7'))) {
   echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
} elseif (preg_match("/hc/i", $drop) && in_array($ruavalue,array('0','1','4','5'))) { ?>
   <form action="" method="post">
      <input name='drop1'     type='hidden' value='<?php echo $drop ?>'>
      <input name='ruavalue1' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $ruavalue ?>'>
      <input name='boss'      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST['tier_two'] ?>'> 
      <input name='main'      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $maintoonqry3 ?>'>
      <input name='the_page'  type='hidden' value='RUA/rua-system.php'>
      <input name='ruasubmit' type='submit' value='RUA!' />
   </form>
<?php 
} elseif (preg_match("/hc/i", $drop) && in_array($ruavalue,array('2','3','6','7'))) { 
   echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
} elseif (preg_match("/myth/i", $drop) &&  in_array($ruavalue,array('0','1','2','3'))) { ?>
   <form action='' method='post'>
   <input name='drop1'     type='hidden' value='<?php echo $drop ?>'>
   <input name='ruavalue1' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $ruavalue ?>'>
   <input name='boss'      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST['tier_two'] ?>'>
   <input name='main'      type='hidden' value='<?php echo $maintoonqry3 ?>'>
   <input name='the_page'  type='hidden' value='RUA/rua-system.php'>
   <input name='ruasubmit' type='submit' value='RUA!' />
   </form>
<?php 
} elseif (preg_match('/myth/i', $drop) &&  in_array($ruavalue,array('4','5','6','7'))) {  
   echo 'You Have RUA\'ed To This Boss';
}
?>
```

Comment: @Prix - yeah... i saw... i went through the whole thing... with the conditions... mixing and's and or's.  i just kind of kept going with it, though.  figured i would post it cleaned up a bit.

Comment: for real.. i bet i could clean it more.  let's see.

Comment: [Probably, but this question literally becomes a duplicate of his other question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23463320/342740)

Comment: oh... so... it's friday night.  i'm bored on stackoverflow.  this is not for points.  i just wrote my first ssh client in python, though... among other things tonight... been jamming out to [ween](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWUu9ckdwHc) and [this NoSQL parody of gangnam style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpK0WAuyOl4).  maybe OP will clean up his (her?) codez.

Comment: I am in no way cursing you for replying it :) I did like your improvements you probably missed a `break` but the main fact here is that he OP didn't took his time to read and learn from the answers given to him.

Comment: @prix I had completely forgotten about that thread it was not my intention to duplicate I do apologise

Comment: @gloomy.penguin wow. thank you very much that is much cleaner and easier to follow i greatly appreciate your help, i will implement this tonight